# Scroll web page by subpixels

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to scroll a web page by sub pixels using JavaScript?

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
document.querySelector('body').scrollTop += 0.5
```

This doesn't work, since scrollTop converts the given number to an integer, which results into cutting off the decimal part of the number.

I'd need this in order to scroll a webpage automatically but very slowly. If I use full pixels the scrolling doesn't look smooth.

The only thing I can think of, is changing `translateY`, since this accepts sub pixels. But that would break my regular scroll behaviour, which is something I'd really like to avoid.

**Edit:**
I've created two JSFiddles to show the differences:

- [scrollTop](http://jsfiddle.net/9a6tnfjz/2/)
- [translateY](http://jsfiddle.net/m2Lza8mw/1/)

They scroll at the same speed. But the first one isn't smooth. However, the second one breaks the native scrolling (you can't scroll to top afterwards). I know that the second one can be fixed by using plugins like iScroll or similar, but if not absolutely necessary, I would like to avoid that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you are not restricted to plain javascript, i would recommend linking jQuery and using the `.animate()` function. will make your life so much easier

Comment: What do you mean by not looking smooth? The smallest unit that can be displayed on the screen is the pixel. That's what the screen resolution is measured by.

Comment: You could look into using the GreenSock animation library. https://greensock.com/ They have put a lot of effort into animation performance. I have noticed using it to animate scrolling has appeared smoother than jQuery animate on a few projects I have used it on.

Comment: Are you really looking up the body element everytime you are updating the scroll position?

Comment: Since a pixel is the smallest unit on a screen, how could you half it? :/

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I've put two JSFiddles together to clarify my issue (see edit above).

Comment: @Pye Well probably the problem only occurs on high-resolution screens, where 1 CSS pixel can map to multiple physical pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the W3C has changed the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#scrolloptionsvertical) for `scrollTop`. Instead of an integer it's now a double. Therefore the solution is to wait until the browser vendors implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This could do.

At the beginning:

```
var scrollValue=document.querySelector('body').scrollTop;
```

In the scrolling loop:

```
scrollValue+=0.5
document.querySelector('body').scrollTop =scrollValue;
```

The scrollValue variable gets incremented by small increments without getting rounded but when used to set the scrollTop the integer value is used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But that is basically the same as I did in the JSFiddles – right? Did you have a look at them?

Comment: @amann as a side note, I don't see subpixel behaviour in the translateY fiddle. Browser differences?

Comment: Really? Ah i guess it only occurs on high resolution screens, since 1 CSS pixel can map to multiple physical pixels on a high resolution screen. I'm viewing it on a MacBook Retina. What kind of display do you have?

Comment: @amann I'm on a 2009 Mac book pro 17", I set the scrollSpeed to 1.0 and clearly can see the "one pixel" steps

Comment: You're right – I can see that too. But the translateY version doesn't make 1 CSS pixel jumps, but rather something less and is also updated a few times per second. The scrollTop version is only updated one time per second and makes a jump of a full CSS pixel. Also 5px per second would definitely be ok for my app and for that speed the translateY solution looks somewhat ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just track the current scroll position with your own variable.  When the scroll position is changed by the user, update your variable.  While your calculations are happening, first change your variable, then translate it to an integer for the browser.